# How to deploy api c# on azure and there is no entity framework migration in publish?

Tags: c#, azure, api

I am trying to publish the api c# on a host service. I tried using Microsoft azure. The api is published but I can get or post the data. I figured out that I couldn't find the entity framework migration option in the publish, so I thought this might be the problem. I need to know how to find this option.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a database (in Azure) and then configure your API with the connection string.  Once you have a DB provisioned, you should be able to run the EF migrations.  There are several ways to do this... in your app code, using dotnet/EF command line, or even from Visual Studio using Package Manager Console.  I do not believe there is an App Service publish option to run an EF migration.

Comment: I used a command in the package console manager, and then I published but it did not work

Comment: I run this command "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef" then this "dotnet ef", what should I do else?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if my workaround helps to fix the issue:
when building the Web Application and connecting to the Azure SQL database server, there is a need of connecting SQL Server Entity framework in my project.

I have run similar command like

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

which was not working and throwing the error like that `tool package cannot be restored` and `dotnet-ef` failed to install, many other errors.

When I run the same command again but with explicitly versioning, then it is worked:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.1
```

Similarly, based on your requirement of the entity framework version and the dotnet version in the project, run that command using versioning which helps to fix the issue.